There are infinitely many proper scoring rules. Are they all equally valid? Or is log loss superior because of its connection to max likelihood?
I'm kind of obsessed with binary loss functions.
How to create a (binary) loss function (scoring rule):

Create a function, $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0} 
$, that is symmetric about $x=\frac12$. $f(x)=f(1-x)$ represents the "weight" that may represent how often we expect to see such a prediction using our model.
Consider, $g(x)=\frac{f(x)}{x}$, this is the derivative of our loss function and ensures it is proper.
Determine our loss function: $G(p)$.

Here are the corresponding weight functions for various loss functions and the interpretation of them:



Loss function
Weight function: f(x)
Inverse Link Function: $x=\int(1/f(y))dy$




Log Loss: $\log(p)$
$1$
Linear: $y=x+\frac12, x\in [-\frac12,\frac12]$


Squared Loss: $-(1-p)^2$
$2x(1-x)$
Logistic: $y=\frac{1}{1+e^{-2x}}$


Spherical Loss: $\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+(1-p)^2}}$
$\frac{x(1-x)}{({x^2+(1-x)^2})^{3/2}}$



Exponential Loss:$-\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}$
$\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x(1-x)}}$



Trigonometric Loss: $\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}\right)$
$\sqrt{x(1-x)}$
Sine: $y=\frac{\sin(x)+1}{2}$, $x\in [-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2]$


0-1 Loss: $H(p-\frac12)$
$\frac12\delta(\frac12)$
Constant: $y=\frac12$, $x\in [-1,1]$


$\int 4\sqrt{p}(1-p)^{\frac{3}{2}} \, dp$
$4(x(1-x))^{3/2}$
Sine(Arctangent): $y=\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x^{2}}}\right)}{2}$


$\int\frac{\sin^2\left(\pi p\right)}{p}$
${\sin^2\left(\pi x\right)}$
$y=\frac{\arctan\left(\pi x\right)}{\pi}+\frac{1}{2}$


$\text{Li}_2(p)-p \ln(p)-(1-p)\ln(1-p)$
$-x \ln(x)-(1-x)\ln(1-x)$



$\frac{5}{2}\left(p-1\right)^{3}\left(3p+1\right)$
$\text{Beta}(3,3)=30(x(1-x))^{2}$




As you can see, there's a multitude of proper loss functions. Any linear combination of proper loss functions creates another one.
Since the weight function for Log Loss is constant, it is the only function that is applicable for $>2$ classes, given the function can only depend on $p$ (note how the other loss functions generally depend on $1-p$). This and the relation to maximum likelihood are why SoftMax and cross-entropy (log) loss go hand in hand.
Squared Loss is most intuitive since it is used for normal distributions. The Trigonometric Loss function is a good middle ground between the two since the weight function corresponds to the standard deviation and the arcsine link function has a finite range (unlike logit), the loss function also has finite range (unlike log loss).
The exponential loss corresponds to infinite weight at 0 and 1, so it has even higher loss for low probabilities than log loss.
0-1 loss (accuracy), while not proper, is the limit when the weight function is a delta function at $\frac12$, making it ideal for truly 50/50 events (e.g. predicting a coin flip). This limit can be reached using a series of loss functions corresponding to weight functions of the form $\text{Beta}(n,n)$ as $n\to\infty$. The opposite of this would be the limit of $\text{Beta}(n,n)$ as $n\to\infty$ which is two delta functions at 0 and 1, this corresponds to $-\infty-0-1$ loss which only gives credit to those with 100% conviction and provides a mathematical framework that quantifies the commonly held sentiment that, "Every event either happens or it doesn't, so that's 2 possibilities. Therefore, it's 50/50. Stuff either happens, or it doesn't."
Viewing loss functions in terms of their weight function allows us to better understand their "robustness".
Less Robust (incentivizes 50/50 predictions, affected more by outliers) <-> More Robust (incentivizes 0/100 predictions, minimally affected by outliers)
$-\infty-0-1$ loss ($n=0$), exponential loss ($n=\frac12$), log loss ($n=1$), trig loss ($n=\frac32$), entropy-based loss ($n\approx \frac74$), probit ($n\approx 1.8111$), squared loss ($n=2$), sin-arctan ($n=\frac52$), spherical loss ($n\approx 2.7445$), $\text{Beta}(3,3)$ based loss ($n=3$), arctan ($n\approx 3.3258$), 0-1 loss ($n=\infty$)
0-1 loss is the most robust since it only has weight at 0.5, the median, while log-loss corresponds to the average since it weighs the entire range [0,1] equally. The least robust is $-\infty-0-1$ loss since it only weights the max and min.
The weight function can correspond to link functions that convert any number from 0 to 1 into a real number. For example, consider a binary variable that uses a logit link function to transform a random variable, $X\in\mathbb{R}$, to $p=\text{logit}(X)\in[0,1]$. Then suppose $X$ is updated via random Gaussian white noise with fixed variance, then $p$ will be updated in proportion to $p(1-p)$, this is the weight function for squared loss.
What troubles me about there being so many valid loss functions is that it means there's no "objective" midpoint between two probabilities.
Given a loss function, $G(p)$, the metric $E(p)=p\cdot G(p)+(1-p)\cdot G(1-p)$ measures the expected loss which is called variance when using squared loss or entropy for log loss.
When a probability changes from $p$ to $q$, the metric $D(p,q)=q\cdot(G(q)-G(p))+(1-q)\cdot G((1-q)-G(1-p))$ measures the divergence.
With these metrics, a simple question to ask is what probability is halfway from $\frac{1}{2}$ (maximum uncertainty) to fully resolved ($0$ or $1$)? More concretely, that means solving $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}E(\frac12)$ which is equivalent to $D(\frac12,x)=E(x)$.
Another question is what is the midpoint between $\frac12$ and $1$. That is, find the $x$ that minimizes $D(\frac12,x)+D(x,1)$. Note that $D(\frac12,x)=E(x)-E(\frac12)$ and $D(x,1)=-G(x)$, so this is equivalent to minimizing $E(x)-G(x)$. Setting the derivative to zero, we need $G(x)-G(1-x)=G'(x)=\frac{W(x)}{x}$.



Loss function
Expected Loss: $E(p)$
Robustness ($\frac{2n}{2n+1}$)
50% Uncertainty: $E(x)=\frac{1}{2}E(\frac12)$
Midpoint: $\min D(\frac12,x)+D(x,1)$




0-1 Loss: $H(p-\frac12)-1$
$-\frac12+|\frac12-p|$
1.0000
$x=\frac14,\frac34=0.2500,0.7500$
$x=\frac12=0.5000$


$\int\frac{\sin^2\left(\pi p\right)}{p}$

0.8693
$x\approx 0.1688,0.8312$
$x\approx0.7229$


$\frac{5}{2}\left(p-1\right)^{3}\left(3p+1\right)$
$-\frac{5}{2}p\left(1-p\right)\left(1+p(1-p)\right)$
0.8571
$x=\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt{12-2\sqrt{26}}}{4}\approx0.1644, 0.8356$
$x\approx0.7296$


Spherical Loss: $\frac{p}{\sqrt{p^2+(1-p)^2}}-1$
$\sqrt{p^2+(1-p)^2}-1$
0.8459
$x=\frac12\pm\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{8}-\frac1{16}}\approx 0.1620, 0.8380$
$x\approx0.7267$


$\int 4\sqrt{p}(1-p)^{\frac{3}{2}} \, dp=\frac{4}{3}\left(p\left(1-p\right)\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}+\frac{1}{2}\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{p}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}+p\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}$
$\frac{1}{2}p\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{p}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\left(1-p\right)\sin^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1-p}\right)+\frac{\left(2p-1\right)^{2}+2}{6}\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}-\frac{\pi}{4}$
0.8333
$x\approx 0.1566, 0.8434$
$x\approx0.7388$


Squared Loss: $-(1-p)^2$
$-p(1-p)$
0.8000
$x=\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt2}{4}\approx0.1464, 0.8536$
$x=\frac34=0.7500$


Probit Loss

0.7837
$x\approx 0.1416, 0.8584$
$x\approx0.7554$


$\text{Li}_2(p)-p \ln(p)-(1-p)\ln(1-p)$
$p\text{Li}_2(p)+(1-p)\text{Li}_2(1-p)-p \ln(p)-(1-p)\ln(1-p)$
0.7778
$x\approx 0.1399, 0.8601$
$x\approx0.7571$


Trigonometric Loss: $\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}-\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}\right)$
$\sqrt{p\left(1-p\right)}-p\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}\right)-\left(1-p\right)\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{p}{1-p}}\right)$
0.7500
$x\approx 0.1322, 0.8678$
$x\approx0.7639$


Log Loss: $\log(p)$
$p\log(p)+(1-p)\log(1-p)$
0.6667
$x\approx 0.1100, 0.8900$
$x\approx0.7822$


Exponential Loss:$-\sqrt{\frac{1-p}{p}}$
${2\sqrt{p(1-p)}}$
0.5000
$x=\frac12\pm \frac{\sqrt3}{4}\approx0.0670, 0.9330$
$x\approx0.8090$


$-\infty--1-0$ loss
$2H(p-1)+2H(-p)-1$
0.000
$x=0.0000,1.0000$
$x=1.0000$




Since loss functions are additive and likelihoods are multiplicative, evaluating a model's skill is equivalent to ensuring their bankroll is proportional to the exponentiated loss. Each of these loss functions corresponds to a utility function, $U(x)$ which is maximized in accordance to the loss function.




Loss function
Exponentiated Loss: $L(x)$
Utility Function: $U(x)=\int(\frac{1}{L^{-1}(x)})dx$




$\ln(x)$
$x$
$\ln(x)$


$2\ln(x)$
$x^2$
$2\sqrt{x}$


$\frac12\ln(x)$
$\sqrt{x}$
$\frac{-1}{x}$


$n\ln(x)$
$x^n$
$\frac{x^{1-\frac1n}}{1-\frac1n}$



Here we see the relation between log loss and the Kelly criterion which optimizes the logarithm of the bankroll, the next rows show that double-Kelly optimizes the square root of the bankroll, while half-Kelly optimizes the inverse of the bankroll.
Note that all valid utility functions must be convex. The limit where the Utility function is linear: $U(x)=x=\frac{x^{1-\frac1n}}{1-\frac1n}, n\to\infty$ corresponds to an infinitely large multiple of log loss.
This is just a huge knowledge dump from my end, so please respond with links to any resources in this area or comment if you have insights.

Welcome to Cross Validated! Does this answer your question? If not, why not?

To be honest, I have not yet read your entire post (but have it bookmarked). Merkle & Steyvers (2013) per the thread Dave notes sounds like a good place to start. Why is LogLoss preferred over other proper scoring rules? is not exactly what you are looking for, but the various criteria that people have proposed to decide between scoring rules and that are discussed there may be useful.

Honestly, my question isn't in terms of practical use, it's more about exploring the theory. Unlike in a linear variable where squared loss is the obvious choice, there are infinitely many ways to view the range 0-1 which is troubling. Supposing Log Loss is best (corresponds to max likelihood) also creates some issues since the KL divergence isn't reflexive. I'm mainly looking for some place where the ideas in my post have already been explored and "resolved" into some unified theory about loss functions.

One use case is where I want to explore the equivalent of random walks in [0,1]. Random walks are well-studied on real numbers since adding noise corresponds to adding a Gaussian with some variance. Using squared-loss makes that possible using the beta distribution. Beta(p*n, (1-p)*n) has mean p and variance p(1-p)*n/(n+1), I'm not sure what the equivalent function is for Log Loss ensuring mean p and entropy (p ln p + (1-p) ln(1-p))*c where c is a constant from 0 to 1.

There are a lot of terminologies I introduced: Betting Criterion <- Utility Functions <- Exponentiated Loss (not sure if applicable to loss functions other than log loss)<- loss function (well known) -> weight function (not that well known) -> link function (more well known). Also, note that the difference between the loss of p and 1-p: G(p)-G(1-p) creates another link function. Link functions define a distance between probabilities (so Log Loss corresponds to logit which has an infinite distance between 0.5 and 1), has the Trigonometric loss I introduced been explored elsewhere?

Sorry if I'm rambling in the comments (like I said, I'm obsessed with this topic), an interpretation of the weight function for squared loss (2p(1-p)) is that it treats [0,1] like a linear variable (constant variance) by down weighting the importance of probabilities near 0 and 1 (relative to log loss which has constant weight function). Essentially, my post poses a multitude of questions that I have a partial, but not complete, understanding of.

@Dave not necessarily since I already understand that question, I also introduced a family of proper loss functions in my post (any symmetric weight function corresponds to a proper loss function), so the questions I'm asking are not necessarily surface-level.

If my question is too vague right now, here's a concrete one based on the ideas I talked about in my post: what is the importance of each game in a 7 game series (assume games are 50/50 for simplicity)? We can define importance as the expected divergence. We'll get a different answer depending on which loss functions we use, so which is "best"? If we use 0-1 loss only games 1, 3, 5, 7 matter when tied, if we use $-\infty$-0-1 loss only the closeout games matter, using squared loss we find the later games matter more, even more with log loss, etc. Which conclusion is "correct"/most useful?

I took the liberty of adding the [tag:references] tag to your question, since that is what you are asking for (and no, I don't know of anything). "Since the weight function for Log Loss is constant, it is the only function that is applicable for >2 classes" - not quite; some people are fine with "non-local" scoring rules, although this is one thing to keep in mind, e.g., for the Brier score - but then, some people also consider the log score explosion for events that were deemed impossible or certain a bug.

"in a linear variable where squared loss is the obvious choice" - it isn't. Quantile modeling and prediction are very much a thing, and there we use pinball losses.

The answer to you question depends on what you mean by "valid" or superior. If you think in terms of the robustness definition that you gave, then it seems that you have already answered your own question.
Since you said that you are interested in theory on proper scoring rules I highly recommend you have a look at Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation by Gneiting and Raftery, 2007. It contains a full characterization of proper scoring rules which you can compare to the construction principle you claim. It also shows that binary proper scoring rules have a mixture representation in terms of asymmetric zero-one scores/losses.
Additionally, I recommend you refine your statements and results to be more precise. For instance, you begin your question with stating that the steps you mention create a scoring rule. Then below your table you say that these scoring rules are in fact proper. And even further down you claim that the 0-1-loss is now suddenly not proper. The latter claim is unfortunately often reproduced, but not correct, see my answer here for more details. It can make a big difference whether a scoring rule is proper, strictly proper, or improper.
